# How does throw work?

Tags: php, exception, throw

I would like to know how `throw` works in PHP.

For example, does it act like a `die()` or `exit()`? How can I know what is done internally?

I am asking this because I saw Kohana using their `$this->redirect()` method with a throw to terminate the script execution instead of the traditional exit.

Comment: Here's the place to start: http://lxr.php.net/

Comment: **@Closevoter(s)** this has nothing to do with SuperUser !

Comment: How "internal" do you want to get here?

Comment: @deceze Obviously he didn't mean how its written in C under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22530701/736809), you use `throw` to throw exceptions that can be caught "further up" in your application.

When you work with objects and object oriented programming you start coding every single object you make as a standalone object that you can give to someone else. The public methods of these are an **API**, and the phpdoc above each public method details what **exceptions** the class might throw under certain circumstances.

So, someone has created a standalone object that does something for you, like writing to a disk. You want to use this object, so you look at the docs and see it throws a `PermissionsException` when the object can't write to the disk because of a permissions issue.

In *your code* that uses this person's object, you now know that you should *catch* that exception, log it, and continue however you want your application to work given that circumstance (show a nice error to the user if it's via an AJAX call, for example).

So, knowing this, when you code your own objects, make *descriptive* exceptions for different circumstances that *someone who you give your object to* can use and respond to in their own applications.

Both `die` and `exit` you don't really want to use in production applications. They're useful for debugging when you do a `var_dump()` and then want to halt application execution straight afterwards or if you want to completely stop the script from running for some reason.

As for why your specific found piece of code does it this way, you should ask the developer if it isn't documented with good reasoning.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ! I will try to dig more about Kohana's redirect()

Comment: I dislike it when the chosen answer starts with "As already explained." Unfortunately, for me, it has not.  You are my first contact with this answer.

Comment: @Hoytman There was a [previous answer that already alluded to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22530701/736809), and this is the explanation referenced. The amount of time it took you to explain how you don't like "as already explained" was a waste; better focus it on something more beneficial for yourself and others. Also, with sufficient privileges you can *edit* and I could accept it, for future reference.

Comment: I am confused by these messages (which appear thought the forum).  As a new visitor to the discussion, It reads as a reprimand to the OP.  Perhaps if it was a link...

Comment: My advice would be to check your attitude when replying to comments - saying you instantly dislike something as a newbie won't get you anywhere. Questioning with respect will. You'll get much further. Also I've updated with your suggestion, thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful

Answer (score 3):

`throw` is not like `exit` or `die` at all. Throwing an exception does not automatically terminate the application, a thrown exception can be *caught* by the application. Only when an exception is *not* caught will the application be terminated.

```
try {
    throw new Exception;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'caught it';
}

echo 'not dead yet';
```

Exceptions are a mechanism to signal errors to higher up callers in a more flexible and rigorous manner than simple `return false` statements would allow. They are not comparable to a simple `exit` or `die`.

I don't know what Kohana does exactly, but throwing an exception instead of using a simple `exit` or `die` is an abuse of exceptions. Exceptions should be thrown in *exceptional* error circumstances only.

Answer (score 0):

Using "throw" without try/catch will terminate the script with a "catchable fatal error". As far as I know there's no benefit in using "throw" this way. If you want to terminate a script you should use exit(), so you don't need to suppress the error message.